# Array size in GetChild method is wrong in ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I implemented ExpandableListView using [this](https://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html) example, the only 2 diff from my code and example code is: I implemented on dialog box instead of activity and 2nd diff is my data is coming from SQLite.

So, I successfully implemented ExpandableListView and data is coming on perfect position according to group/child pos also. There is no issue in the code.

Now, later I implemented search functionality in the same ExpandableListAdapter.

**Problem:** Suppose, I want to search Electricity, (which is twice in my case also "E" is matching in more than one time) So, when I search "E", it shows me a list of matches with "E" and that is good, but when I do the second letter "L" it crashes on getChild method and tells me that index is "1" and size is "1" I know it should be 2, but I don't know how is it possible? Because the same getChild method works when it shows me the ExpandableList!!

I tried to debug also, that main Group size is coming right for the first time, but later it remains zero (0).

***See:***

[image]

**Code:**

**Dialog Class:**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Adapter.CustomSpinnerAdapter;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Adapter.CustomSpinnerClass;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Adapter.DialogListAdapter;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Adapter.ExpandableCategoryAdapter;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Interface.CategoryListener;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Interface.HamburgerMenuListener;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Interface.ResultListener;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.CategoryHeader;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.CategoryResponse;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.CustomCategory;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.General;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.ProvidersInfo;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.Reminder;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.R;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.RestApi.ApiClient;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.RestApi.ApiInterface;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DatabaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.CUSTOM_CATEGORY_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.PROVIDER_CATEGORY_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.PROVIDER_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.REMINDER_CATEGORY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.REMINDER_CATEGORY_ALIAS_NAME;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.REMINDER_CATEGORY_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.REMINDER_CATEGORY_OWNER_NAME;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.REMINDER_CATEGORY_PROVIDER_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.REMINDER_CATEGORY_PROVIDER_NAME;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.REMINDER_CATEGORY_PROVIDER_NUMBER;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.REMINDER_CATEGORY_SUB_PROVIDER_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Sql.DataBaseConstant.SUB_PROVIDER_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.CUSTOM_HEADER;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.ELECTRICITY_BILL;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.ELECTRICITY_BILL_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.GAS;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.GAS_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.GENERAL_HEADER;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.INSURANCE;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.INSURANCE_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.LANDLINE;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.LANDLINE_ID;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.NO_CATEGORY;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.OTHER_HEADER;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.PHONE_NUMBER;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.PICK_PROVIDER_CODE;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.PROFILE;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.RESULT_FAILED;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.RESULT_OKAY;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.WATER_BILL;
import static com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils.WATER_BILL_ID;


public class CategoryDialog extends BaseClass implements View.OnClickListener, Callback<String>, HamburgerMenuListener, ResultListener {
    private static final String TAG = CategoryDialog.class.getSimpleName();
    int i = 0;
    private String landlineName, getProviderName, defaultName = "", phoneNum, customCategoryName, selected = "", getConsumerNum, getAccountNum, getOwnerName;
    private long tempId = 0, categoryId, getCustomCategoryId, providerId, customCategoryId = 0, subProviderId;
    private boolean stop = true, insurance, isEditPayment = false, isDeletedSQLite = false, isDeletedServer = false, isClicked = false;
    private ExpandableCategoryAdapter expandableCategoryAdapter;
    private List<CustomCategory> categories, customCategories;
    private RecyclerView dialogRecyclerView;
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    private DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter;
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences profilePreference;
    private View promptsView;
    private CustomCategory customCategory;
    private List<Reminder> dialogListItems;
    private ImageView info, search, close;
    private DialogListAdapter dialogListAdapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private ProviderDialog providerDialog;
    private TextView categoryToolbar, title, inputInsuranceProvider, textViewError, inputBillProvider, errorView, information, subProviderError, providerError, customProviderError, consumerError, ownerError;
    private EditText searchText, userInput, inputConsumerNumber, name, inputAccountNumber, inputCustomProvider;
    private ProvidersInfo providersInfo;
    private AlertDialog informationDialog, mDialog;
    private CategoryListener categoryListener;
    private General provider, subProvider;
    private RelativeLayout relativeProvider, subProviderLayout, accountLayout, customLayout;
    private LinearLayout spinnerLayout;
    private List<General> mainInsuranceList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CustomSpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter;
    private CustomSpinnerClass spinInsuranceList;
    private ArrayList<CategoryHeader> headerArrayList = new ArrayList<CategoryHeader>();
    private CategoryHeader categoryHeader;

    public CategoryDialog(Context context, Activity activity) {
        super(context, activity);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
    }

    private void init() {
        categories = new ArrayList<>();
        customCategories = new ArrayList<>();
        dbAdapter = RemindMe.getInstance().adapter;
        search = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.search);
        close = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.close);
        categoryToolbar = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.category_toolbar);
        searchText = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.search_text);
        dialogListItems = new ArrayList<>();
        profilePreference = context.getSharedPreferences(PROFILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        providerDialog = new ProviderDialog(context);
        providerDialog.setResultListener(this);
        getDataFromSharedPref();
    }

    private void search() {
        searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                expandableCategoryAdapter.filterData(s.toString());
                if (count == 0) {
                    if (headerArrayList.size() == 0) {
                        loadSomeData();
                    }
                    expandAll();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void loadSomeData() {
        categoryHeader = new CategoryHeader(GENERAL_HEADER, categories);
        headerArrayList.add(categoryHeader);

        categoryHeader = new CategoryHeader(OTHER_HEADER, categories);
        headerArrayList.add(categoryHeader);

        categoryHeader = new CategoryHeader(CUSTOM_HEADER, customCategories);
        headerArrayList.add(categoryHeader);
    }

    public void setCategoryListener(CategoryListener listener) {
        this.categoryListener = listener;
    }

    private void setClickListener() {
        search.setOnClickListener(this);
        close.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void showCategoryDialog() {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_category_dialog_layout, null);
        init();
        findViewById();
        setClickListener();


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);


        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.add), null);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel), null);


        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);


        recyclerView();
        search();
        mDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);


        mDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                Button buttonNegative = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        isEditPayment = false;
                        showDialogBox(0);
                    }
                });

                buttonNegative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        mDialog.show();
    }


    private void findViewById() {
        expandableListView = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
    }

    private void recyclerView() {
        loadArrayListData();
        expandableCategoryAdapter = new ExpandableCategoryAdapter(context, headerArrayList, this);
        try {
            expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableCategoryAdapter);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //method to expand all groups
    private void expandAll() {
        int count = expandableCategoryAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            expandableListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }
```

**ExpandableListAdapter:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Interface.HamburgerMenuListener;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.CategoryHeader;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Model.CustomCategory;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.R;
import com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CommonUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableCategoryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = ExpandableCategoryAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private List<CategoryHeader> originalList;
    private List<CategoryHeader> headerList;
    private HamburgerMenuListener menuInterface;

    public ExpandableCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryHeader> generalList, HamburgerMenuListener menuInterface) {
        this.context = context;
        this.headerList = new ArrayList<CategoryHeader>();
        this.headerList.addAll(generalList);
        this.originalList = generalList;
        this.menuInterface = menuInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        List<CustomCategory> countryList = headerList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryList();
        return countryList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        CustomCategory customCategory = (CustomCategory) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_general_list, null);
        }

        TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_item);
        ImageView icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_category_icon);
        Button logo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_custom_category_icon);
        ImageView hamburgerMenu = convertView.findViewById(R.id.hamburger_menu);

        if (customCategory != null) {
            if (customCategory.getCustCategoryName() != null) {
                name.setText(customCategory.getCustCategoryName().trim());
            }

            if (customCategory.getIcon() != null && customCategory.getCustCategoryId() <= CommonUtils.WATER_BILL_ID) {
                icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hamburgerMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                icon.setImageResource(resources.getIdentifier(customCategory.getIcon(), "drawable",
                        context.getPackageName()));
            } else {
                icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                hamburgerMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                logo.setText(customCategory.getCustCategoryName().substring(0, 1));
            }
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                menuInterface.onClickListItem(headerList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryList().get(childPosition).getCustCategoryId());
            }
        });


        hamburgerMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (menuInterface != null) {
                    menuInterface.onClickHamburger(headerList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryList().get(childPosition).getCustCategoryId());
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        if (headerList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderName().equals(CommonUtils.GENERAL_HEADER)) {
            return CommonUtils.LANDLINE_ID;
        }

        if (headerList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderName().equals(CommonUtils.OTHER_HEADER)) {
            return CommonUtils.WATER_BILL_ID;
        }


        return headerList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryList().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return headerList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return headerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    private void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }


    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        CategoryHeader categoryHeader = (CategoryHeader) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_custom_category_list, null);
        }

        TextView heading = view.findViewById(R.id.header_view);
        heading.setText(categoryHeader.getHeaderName().trim());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void filterData(String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        headerList.clear();

        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            headerList.addAll(originalList);
        } else {

            for (CategoryHeader categoryHeader : originalList) {

                List<CustomCategory> categoryList = categoryHeader.getCategoryList();
                List<CustomCategory> newList = new ArrayList<CustomCategory>();
                for (CustomCategory customCategory : categoryList) {
                    if (customCategory.getCustCategoryName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                        newList.add(customCategory);
                    }
                }
                if (newList.size() > 0) {
                    CategoryHeader nContinent = new CategoryHeader(categoryHeader.getHeaderName(), newList);
                    headerList.add(nContinent);
                }
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding separate arraylist according to header name. Also added field/tag in databse.

```
 private void loadSomeData() {
        List<CustomCategory> generalCategories = new ArrayList<>();
        generalCategories.addAll(dbAdapter.getCategoryById(null, 0, GENERAL_HEADER));

        List<CustomCategory> otherCategories = new ArrayList<>();
        otherCategories.addAll(dbAdapter.getCategoryById(null, 0, OTHER_HEADER));


        categoryHeader = new CategoryHeader(GENERAL_HEADER, generalCategories);
        headerArrayList.add(categoryHeader);

        categoryHeader = new CategoryHeader(OTHER_HEADER, otherCategories);
        headerArrayList.add(categoryHeader);

        categoryHeader = new CategoryHeader(CUSTOM_HEADER, customCategories);
        headerArrayList.add(categoryHeader);
    }
```